# How does one protect electrical in a 2x4 flat studded wall?

Tags: electrical

I'm notching the back of some flat 2x4 studs for electrical to run through (hence my wire is much less than 1.5" deep.

Does one just put two 1.5" wide nail plates side by side or is there a better way?

Note: I've found examples of double studs (1.5"+1.5" = 3") done this way, just never a true flat stud.

Note 2: Before someone asks, these 2x4s are for nailing only and non-structural so don't get distracted worry about the notch.

Comment: Is NM your only option for a wiring method here?

Comment: I have run the wires in the ceiling yes you have to have a box accessible at each splice but they can be decorated, just have be able to open them with a screwdriver. The 2 screws that hold the cover on.

Answer (score 1):

I use these behind large-volume boxes in 2x4 walls, to protect the entry point of the box. They should also work for your purpose. They are 5" x 8" self-nailing steel plates:

[image]

The example I got was Oatey 33899, but I'm sure there are other manufacturers. They are cheap (less than $1 each).
An example of a supplier, not a specific endorsement: https://www.supplyhouse.com/sh/control/product/~product_id=33899

Answer (score 0):

you COULD get some thick guage metal flashing and run  it along the opposite side of the stud, however im a plumber and whenever I run into this kind of issue I normally just go with a couple extra nail plates.  I suggest seting them perpendicular to the direction the wire runs and line the width of the stud with them.